# Hamiltonicity of rectangular grids

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Given a rectangular grid of dimensions $5 \times 9$, find if it contains any Hamiltonian cycle in it or not. Can the result be generalized for dimensions $m \times n.$

**Example**

[image: Example]

I have tried making grids on paper and found that Hamiltonian circuits are easy to build if any(or both) of the dimensions are even, however I couldn't prove and generalize my observation.

Any help is much appreciated.